# What is happening in these MULTIOS redirections?

Tags: shell, zsh, io-redirection

When I run `1>&2 echo hi |& grep hi`, I get a non-colored hi followed by a red hi on a new line. This is the same output as `1>&2 echo hi | grep hi`. Why aren’t both of the “hi”s red in the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first pipeline:

```
1>&2 echo hi |& grep hi
```

This is the same as

```
echo hi 1>&2 2>&1 | grep hi
```

since `|&` is the same as `2>&1 |`.

With the `MULTIOS` shell option set, this would duplicate the output of `echo` to standard error.  This produces the un-coloured `hi` that `grep` never sees.  The other `hi` goes through `grep` and is coloured.

The `2>&1` redirection does not do anything as there is no output to standard error from `echo`.  It would be different if you had e.g.

```
{ echo hi 1>&2; } 2>&1 | grep hi
```

or

```
{ echo hi 1>&2; } |& grep hi
```

where the standard output from `echo` would *not* be duplicated and the standard error of the `{ ...; }` would have been sent to `grep`, producing a single coloured `hi`.

Your second pipeline,

```
1>&2 echo hi | grep hi
```

or,

```
echo hi 1>&2 | grep hi
```

(which is the same as your first pipeline with the no-op `2>&1` redirection removed) also redirects standard output twice; once to standard error (the un-coloured `hi`), and to the pipe (the coloured `hi`).

For two coloured `hi`'s:

```
echo hi 2>&1 1>&2 | grep hi
```

or

```
echo hi 1>&1 | grep hi
```

---

(This is with a tiny bit of handwaving as I'm not quite used to the `zsh` shell)